# list comprehension error

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Can someone help me to correct this list comprehension:

```
line_list = [line for line in file.splitlines() if item in line for item in my_list]
```

Because I get the following error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it a bit scrambled:

```
line_list = [line for line in file.splitlines() for item in my_list if item in line]
```

The filter goes at the end.

Also note that the above might put multiple duplicate lines in a row if there is more than one match in `my_list`. The following will check if there are any matches, then add the line only once:

```
line_list = [line for line in file.splitlines() if any(item in line for item in my_list)]
```

Comment: does `any` short-circuits like `next` does, as soon as there is one element of the iterator for which the expression evaluates to True?

Comment: Yes, `any()` and `all()` will short-circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The full loops look like this:

```
line_list = []
for line in file.splitlines():
    for item in my_list:
        if item in line:
            line_list.append(line)
```

Put in the same line, something like this (not true Python syntax):

```
line_list = []
for line in file.splitlines(): for item in my_list: if item in line: line_list.append(line)
```

Of course, the `.append()` part is common to all comprehensions, so we put it at the beginning:

```
line_list = [line for line in file.splitlines() for item in my_list if item in line]
```

If you just think of list comprehensions like that, it should be easy to figure out what order is used.

Don't let it confuse you when you have `else` statements.  For example:

```
line_list = []
for line in file.splitlines():
    if line == "yes":
        line_list.append("no")
    else:
        line_list.append(line)
```

would be interpreted to:

```
line_list = ["no" if line == "yes" else line for line in file.splitlines()]
```

with the `if`-`else` at the beginning.  Why? you ask.  Well, it could have been written like this:

```
line_list = []
for line in file.splitlines():
    line_list.append("no" if line == "yes" else line)
```

You see, the part at the beginning of the comprehension is still the same as what is passed to `.append()`.  The `else` clause is not part of the syntax for the comprehension; it is a separate feature of the language.

---

@TigerhawkT3 made a good point about using `any()`, though.

Comment: Very interesting/clear explanation about how to interpret the comprehensions!